# C# Read .txt file into arrays and listBox

Tags: c#, listbox, readfile

I am making a program in C# for accessing and storing passwords, as a school project.

I have a text file, passwords.txt, with account names and the associated passwords as such:

gmailUsername:gmailPassword
facebookUsername:facebookPassword

So colon (:) between username and password and new line for new site/account whatever.
In the Windows Form i have a listBox that should get its items (only accounts) from reading the passwords.txt file.
Once a item from the listBox has been selected, a textbox in the same Form should show only that associated password from that same text file.

How can I code this? I am stuck on trying to figure out how to read the file and putting all profile entries into an array, then adding these as list items in the listBox. And putting all passwords into another array.

Comment: - Read the file line by line

- Use string.split to separate the data at the colon

- First element in the split array is the username, second element is the password
- Store the data appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

This code would do the job.
You need to create a form with a ListBox named "listBox1" and a TextBox named "textBox1".

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Account> Accounts = new List<Account>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Accounts.Clear();
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("passwords.txt"))
        {
            int pos = line.IndexOf(':');
            if (pos > 0)
            {
                Accounts.Add(new Account() { Service = line[0..pos], Password = line[(pos + 1)..] });
            }
        }
        listBox1.DataSource = Accounts;
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = ((sender as ListBox)?.SelectedItem as Account)?.Password;
    }
}

class Account
{
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Service;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm fairly new to C# so I will look into it.

Comment: Could you please give us some errors messages? I compiled this using VS2019 and a Windows Forms (.NET) project. May you are using another framework ou C# version?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i ended up with. Changed the method slightly. Used List instead of an array.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PSN_PasswordManager
{
    public partial class FormVaultUnlocked : Form
    {

        List<string> myAccounts = new List<string>();
        List<string> myPasswords = new List<string>();

        string[] passLines;
        

        public FormVaultUnlocked()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getProfiles();
        }

        private void lstProfiles_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       // When new list item is chosen

            // Gets selected item (string)
            string curItem = lstProfiles.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //MessageBox.Show(curItem); //testing

            string tempPassword = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < myAccounts.Count; i++)
            {
                if (myAccounts[i] == curItem)
                {
                    tempPassword = myPasswords[i];
                }
            }

            txtPassword.Text = tempPassword;







            string showPassword = "yeet";
            //txtPassword.Text = showPassword;




        }


        void getProfiles()
        {
            // Lese tekstfil
            string[] passLines = File.ReadLines("passwords.txt").ToArray();

            // Legge til items fra array til listBox
            foreach (string profile in passLines)
            {
                // splitting acc. and pass. into strings in new array.
                // account[0] is account name. account[1] is password.
                string[] accPass = profile.Split(':');

                // adds account as list items. And accounts and passwords to global lists.
                lstProfiles.Items.Add(accPass[0].ToString());
                myAccounts.Add(accPass[0]);
                myPasswords.Add(accPass[1]);
            }


        }
    }
}
```